# Which work of Shakespeare "oftentimes better than a master of one" appears in if it it accredited to him?

Tags: phrases, phrase-origin, literature, popular-refrains, shakespeare

*A jack of all trades is a master of none, but oftentimes better than a master of one* is apparently accredited to William Shakespeare.
Just to clarify - I mean the FULL quote, not just 'Jack of all trades' part.

Is there a book, poem, or work by Shakespeare that proves he is the author?

I have searched through the complete works of Shakespeare and couldn't find any phrase like this.

Comment: Some stuff on the Net attributes it to Shakespeare, but [*The idiom 'jack of the trades, master of none' originates from Elizabethan English. The idiom was **famously used** by **Robert Greene in his 1592 booklet 'Greene's Groats-Worth of Wit'** where he refers to William Shakespeare with this idiom.*](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/phrases/jack-of-all-trades-master-of-none)

Comment: I have just searched through this book and could see that word Jack appears only once there in a completely different context. Here is a link to the PDF https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Greene_s_Groats_worth_of_Wit/02VIAQAAMAAJ

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_of_all_trades,_master_of_none), the actual phrase used by Greene was **Johannes Factotum** (Latin for 'John who does everything').

Comment: I regret and disown my closevote. The full OED says *The earliest known use of the phrase **Jack of all trades** is in the early 1600s. OED's earliest evidence for **Jack of all trades** is from 1618, in the writing of G. Mynshul.* But they don't have the ***master of none*** part, the nearest equivalent of which seems to be *1721 **Jack of all Trades; and it would seem, Good at none.** Boston News-letter* and *c1768 **The Jovial Gamester; or, Jack of all Trades, and Master of none.** (title page) - Jovial Gamester's Garland.*

Comment: See [Is "Jack of all trades, master of none" really just a part of a longer proverb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/408782/191178) for the origin of these phrases. Why do you think that Shakespeare said it?

Comment: @Laurel If you're not sure where a phrase came from, Shakespeare is often a good guess. He's the source of a surprising number of idioms.

Comment: This seems like it would be a better question for [literature.se].

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I was brushing the question aside while voting to close, because the text in my first quote was the second snippet returned by googling "jack of all trades etymology". But now I've retracted my closevote, I can't vote to close it ***again*** in favour of [Is "Jack of all trades, master of none" really just a part of a longer proverb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408782/is-jack-of-all-trades-master-of-none-really-just-a-part-of-a-longer-proverb) It obviously ***is*** a duplicate, though, imho.

Comment: I realize "Jack of all trades" wasn't invented by Shakespeare. But "often times better than a master of one" was probably added by him. Where (which poem) exactly?